# PHP Variable does not appear instantiated in View.

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Trying to use PHP MVC

Code in demo.ctrl.php

```
$TPL['username'] = "BOB";   
$TPL['title'] = "Template Demo"; 
include demo.view.php;
```

Code in the demo.view.php

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title><?=$TPL['title']?></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1> Welcome <?=$TPL['username'];?></h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

HTML Output:

Welcome 
**Notice: Undefined variable: TPL in C:\root\php_demo\demo.view.php on line 6**

If I click on ctrl.demo.php

I get these errors:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant demo - assumed 'demo' in
>   C:\root\php_demo\demo.ctrl.php
>   on line 5
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant view - assumed 'view' in
>   C:\root\php_demo\demo.ctrl.php
>   on line 5
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in
>   C:\root\php_demo\demo.ctrl.php
>   on line 5
>
> Warning: include(demoviewphp): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   C:\root\php_demo\demo.ctrl.php
>   on line 5
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'demoviewphp' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\root\php_demo\demo.ctrl.php
>   on line 5

Both files are in the same folder.

Comment: `include 'demo.view.php';` (add quotation marks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include()` needs a string:

```
include "demo.view.php";
```

With your current code PHP tries to build a string by concatenating `.` what it assums to be constant variables that are not defined so it concatenates `.` them as strings.  Yielding `demoviewphp`.